# What is the meaning of “Review process will be blind to review”?

Tags: publications, peer-review, independent-researcher

I am new to publishing and want to publish a paper as an independent researcher. The conference I want to submit this paper to states the following on their website regarding the review process:

> Review process will be blind to review.

Does it imply that the review process is double blind? If not, would stating my affiliation as an independent researcher have any negative impact?

I am currently working for a startup company and worked on this paper in my spare time. Since the company is not associated with my research, I decided not to put in the company as an affiliation.

Comment: If that is the exact quote, it means the conference is not very thorough with spellchecking its website.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: The quote seems to be exact. [An Internet search for that sentence](https://www.google.de/search?q="Review+process+will+be+blind+to+review.") returns exactly one result, which happens to be a conference website.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Oh my. That website plays an audio ad when I visit. Bad sign.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft And yet from a couple of cursory Google searches it does appear to be an IEEE conference, so I would take that to indicate high quality. Hmm, maybe also different cultural norms about conference sites in different parts of the world are in play here? Anyway, I concur--it's just confusingly worded.

Comment: @Philip That depends on what you mean by "an IEEE conference". Just being associated loosely with IEEE is not a mark of quality in itself.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Fair enough. Perhaps I'm wrong to think anything in this directory would have IEEE's imprimatur: https://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/search/index.html . As it happens this same university has hosted all 4 instances of this conference.

Comment: @Philip As far as I can tell, the 2017 version of the conference is not listed there, only the earlier ones.

Comment: My guess: If the reviewers try to read the submission, the conference organizer will poke their eyes so that the reviewers will be too blind to read anything, leaving them only to accept every submission.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft the 2017 version has been listed in the directory. That's actually what gave me the confidence that it wasn't exactly a fake conference. Am I wrong?

Comment: That's interesting. I was not able to find it in that directory, at least by searching for the acronym (which found the earlier versions).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Sorry to bother you about this, but should I be more concerned? I didn't think much of it earlier. Anyway, this is the link : https://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/conferencedetails/index.html?Conf_ID=41247

Comment: I can't comment very well, as I am simply not familiar with conferences in this field.

Comment: @Philip IEEE is notorious for sponsoring low-quality conferences.

Answer (score 6):

This *sounds* like it means double-blind review, but it is not really clear; the phrasing is not standard nor grammatically correct.  If it is important to you, you should contact the conference organizers and ask for clarification.

Answer (score -1):

Actually I wanted to comment with "why would you want to submit exactly there", but I am too new here, reputation must be damned! I am confused over the formulation, too.

For experience, someone on the PC would sight the submissions and tell you if something is not Ok. Depending on the size of the conference, however, it might just be a desk reject.

You might want to contact the PC chair and ask.

Well, here are also some suggestions for alternatives, if your focus is image processing. The list is not exhaustive.

Conferences:

- CVPR
- SIGGRAPH Asia
- Pacific Graphics
- MICCAI
- Vis
- SIGGRAPH of course, but top-level and expensive
- ICCV (heard too litle about it)
- ICMR (heard too litle about it)
- GraVisMa (heard too litle about it)
- Bioimaging (heard too litle about it)

Journals:

- IEEE TVCG
- IEEE TMI
- The Visual Computer
- Computer Graphics Forum
- ACM TOG (very high-reach)

I don't know of you picked the conference based on location, but submitting to a journal could also broadcast your result and you don't need to travel. For talking to people a conference is obviously better.

Comment: Thanks for the list. You are right; I did choose the conference based on location. Also, I don't think my paper is good enough to actually get through the review process for these journals.